# Commented lines in named.conf are still interpreted

Tags: 14.04, server, dns, bind

I recently found out that my domain (set up on a Trusty dedicated server) was not resolved anymore.
I didn't notice it soon enough to be sure (server not "in production" yet, it's considered a "side project"...), but I think the problem came up after an apt-get upgrade...

I did a

```
root@mydomain:/etc/bind# named-checkzone mydomain.tld /etc/bind/named.conf
```

And surprisingly got this:

```
/etc/bind/named.conf:1: unknown RR type 'This'
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/named.conf:3: unexpected end of line
dns_master_load: /etc/bind/named.conf:2: unexpected end of input
/etc/bind/named.conf:4: unknown RR type 'structure'
/etc/bind/named.conf:5: unknown RR type 'this'
...
```

Long story short: it seems the commented lines are interpreted!

Here is the original named.conf file

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

//Zone domaine de test
zone "mydomain.tld" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.mydomain.tld";
  allow-transfer { trusted; wtfdns; };
  allow-query { any; };
  };
```

Is that a "new", expected Bind9 "feature"?
I tried the # and the / * ...* / methods, but none seems to work!
**How are we supposed to comment things out???**
And worse: if the generated files are messed up, how can we trust Bind9

I found several posts on obscure forums about the same problem, usually "solved" by removing all commented lines.

I don't want to be an a$$h01e to the guy that will inherit that, so I will need to leave comments here and there!

Comment: `named-checkzone` must be run on a zone file. Did you mean `named-checkconf`?

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks, you're right! I should have noticed... note for self: better sleep than wasting hours looking for an issue that doesn't exist...

Comment: One normally does not edit `/etc/bind/named.conf`, but rather edits `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` for their own DNS stuff.